# List of class method not autocompleting in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to python and I have a question about autocompletion of method calls on an object within a list using Pycharm.

I have a class called foo():

```
class foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 10


    def getNum(self):
        return self.num
```

I then create a list called `myList` and append a `foo()` object to it. For some reason when I go to try and call the object the method doesn't show up.

[image]

However, if I complete the code with `print(myList[0].getNum())`, it will indeed print out 10.

Also, if I simply create a variable `x` and assign it to a `foo()` object, it will show up just fine like so:
[image]

I tried to create a `y` variable and assign it to `myList[0]` to see if I can get the method to show up, but still no luck.[image]

Is this just an IDE issue or is there a bigger picture that I am missing when doing method calls working with objects inside of list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that python has dynamic typing.  There is no constraint that myList must contain ONLY foo objects.  So PyCharm can't know that myList[0] is a foo to give you the autocomplete for foo (that's only known at runtime).

Take this example:

```
class foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 10


    def getNum(self):
        return self.num

class bar(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 10


    def getNum2(self):
        return self.num

myList = []
myList.append(foo())
myList.append(bar())
print(myList[0])
```

PyCharm doesn't know whether to give you the autocomplete for foo() or bar() so it doesn't give you either.

The last case regarding x works because you explicitly assigned x as a foo object, so Pycharm knows and gives you the autocomplete for foo.

Comment: @NickWesenman Thanks. That cleared up a lot of confusion for me. My only concern is what if your program becomes very large at scale and that your classes have a high amount of methods. Would the only way to go about that is go back and forth between the code and the class to see what methods are in there?

Comment: You've identified a disadvantage to using dynamically typed languages. :)  Yea I often have it open on another monitorif I have to frequently reference it.  You'll never be able to get the auto code completion that you get with IntelliJ (JetBrains' version of the statically typed Java).

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure this is an IDE issue as it may not trace the variable all the way back to its original calls until actually ran. so with you setting x directly to foo() was one assignment but setting y = myList[0] and then getting the object at myList[0] which would be another call back to the variable if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

From python 3.5, you can use [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) which provides advanced typing feature that pyCharm can use to suggest autocompletion.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971921/2696355 for an example and the `typing` doc for more information