# Array of certain types in Python

Tags: python

There is how we define arrays in python:

```
a = []
```

and it can contains any elements of any types. here is my question:

I have a class:

```
class Foo:
   def __init(self,length:int):
       self.__length = length

   @property
   def Length(self) -> int
       return self.__length
```

in my `main` I want to define an array of type `Foo` so I can have access to it's properties, method , etc using intelliscense of an IDE like pyCharm.

How can I declare an array like this?

```
foos: Foo[]
```

Comment: Not sure this is possible - per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835786/list-of-class-method-not-autocompleting-in-pycharm)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question, can you explain things a bit more? It isn’t clear if Foo is meant to be the sequence or the element. _There is how we define arrays in python:_ No, that’s a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure "basic" Python your cannot (AFAIK)

That said, you could be greatly interested in using the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) package which provides ways to define custom types that are recognised and handled by pyCharm autocompletion mechanism when used with type hints.

From your example, you can do this:

```
from typing import List
from somewhere import Foo

FooArray = List[Foo]

def bar(foos: FooArray) -> None:
    for foo in foos:
        print(foo.Length)  # pyCharm suggests the `Length` property
```